# Crear una función con VBA que me diga si en una celda hay determinados valores

Tags: vba

Voy a tener una serie de celdas con texto y también voy a tener un rango de 2 columnas, por ejemplo, en *A2:B50*. Me gustaría crear una función que tuviera 2 inputs, la celda sobre la que quiero trabajar y un rango que será el que tengo en *A2:B50*.

La función debe buscar si en la celda hay alguna de las palabras de la columna A y, si es así, que me devuelva la palabra contigua en la columna B con una especie de *VLOOKUP* o similar. Caso de que no encuentre ninguna de las palabras de la columna A que directamente devuelva algún mensaje de error.

Estoy intentando crear la función con *InStr* y algo parecido a:

```
Function DEVUELVE(rango, celda)
Dim rango As Range
For Each palabra In rango
If InStr(palabra, celda) > 0 Then
DEVUELVE = VLOOKUP(palabra;rango;2;FALSE)
Else: DEVUELVE = "???"
End If
Next
End Function
```

Pero claramente estoy muy verde aún para *tanta sofisticación*.

Answer (score 0):

El código que planteas va por buen camino, así que aquí te brindo una mano con algunos ajustes sobre él:

```
Function DEVUELVE(rango As Range, celda As Range) As Variant
Dim palabra As Range

For Each palabra In rango.Columns(1).Cells
    If InStr(1, celda.Value, palabra.Value) > 0 Then
        DEVUELVE = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(palabra.Value, rango, 2, False)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next palabra

DEVUELVE = "???"
End Function
```

De esta forma, el código va a buscar el texto del segundo argumento de la función en el rango del primer argumento de la misma. Si el hallazgo es verdadero, te va a entregar el valor de la enésima celda de la columna colindante, si no, te va a devolver *'???'*. Llámala usando:

```
=DEVUELVE(rango, palabra)
```